# Time complexity of recursive function with 4 recursive calls

Tags: c, recursion, time-complexity

I've written an algorithm that solves the coin line / gold pots problem where each player in his turn needs to choose a coin from one of the edges.
Now my question is about the recursive function that checks what the most profitable action is. 
Since there are 4 recursive calls I'm not sure what to make of that.
Any hints?

```
int get_profit(int* a, int i, int j) {

if (i == j)
    return a[i];
if (j == i + 1)
    return fmax(a[i], a[j]);

int profit1 = a[i] + fmin(get_profit(a, i + 2, j), get_profit(a, i + 1, j - 1)); // pick left number
int profit2 = a[j] + fmin(get_profit(a, i + 1, j - 1), get_profit(a, i, j - 2)); // pick right number

//if it's better to pick the left number, return the profit from the left number
//else, return the profit from the right number
return fmax(profit1, profit2);
```

}

Comment: I'm not convinced that there always needs to be 4 recursive calls, though as implemented thats probably what happens, and also reasonable for looking at worst case complexity.

Comment: Some complexity classes might talk about this thing called the master theorem which can be adapted to handle this.

Comment: Have you tried evaluating this algorithm on paper on some example values of a, and looking at what it does?

Comment: "coin line / gold pots problem where each player in his turn needs to choose a coin from one of the edges". Sorry, I'm not familiar with this problem. Can you explain it in greater detail? If it's a two-player game, why would you use 4 recursive calls per frame when only one player can move on that turn? Wouldn't you need a [minimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax)-style algorithm? Thanks.

Comment: PiRocks hi I passed the Data Structures course where we learned the master theorm, though there were no such examples there, everything we had was a bit simpler. Are you suggesting that a possible formula would be T(n)=4*T(n-1) + 1? if so I can calculate that but I think it would be 2 to the power of 2 at least, and Im really not sure about that.

Comment: ggorlen It's a dynamic programming problem, where there is a line of coins, and each player in it's pick's a coin but only from one of the edges of the line. Picking the biggest coin not always the best option, and assuming your opponent is as smart as you, you need to propose an algorithm that suggests what the best choice would be. In the case of 4,16,3,1, and It's my turn, choosing 4 would be a bad idea since the other player will take the 16. The algorithm calculates which outcome is better.